# Listen button click event then send to main activity

Tags: android

I have a fragment and I am listening button click event.I am using this code:

```
           button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   if (usernameL.getText().toString().equals("") == false && passwordL.getText().toString().equals("") == false) {
                       final String usernameVal=usernameL.getText().toString();
                       final String passwordVal=passwordL.getText().toString();
                       ((MainActivity)getActivity()).login(usernameVal,passwordVal);
                   }
               } 
           });
```

Is this a good approach ? If it is wrong,how should be ?

Comment: Are you trying to send Username and Password to another activity?? Why dont you use intents??

Comment: I have one activity.This is a fragment inside main activity

Comment: Ok maybe its not very clear what would you like to do??Listen button click event then send to main activity is not a very clear question. Can you tell me what exactly you want to do??

Comment: He's trying to send an event from a fragment to the owning activity.

Comment: It is working I am just asking is this a good approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work, but its not the best way to do it.  The problem with it is that it ties your fragment to MainActivity-  ideally a fragment shouldn't know what activity launches it.  The better solution is to use a callback interface.  Have your fragment define an interface:

```
public interface LoginCallback{
    onLoginPressed(String user, String pword);
}
```

Then have a function in the fragment setLoginCallback(LoginCallback) which sets an instance of LoginCallback.  When the user presses the button, call onLoginPressed on that instance.

Your Activity will either create an object of type LoginCallback, or will implement the interface itself.

The advantage of this is the Fragment will not need to know anything about the Activity-  its self contained.  The disadvantage is a little more work to set up the fragment (you need to set the login callback) in the activity.

Comment: If I don't want to send username and password to activity,can i use this method for send to my server these datas ? (inside onclick method)

Comment: Yes.  A usual way of doing this would be to have the LoginFragment deal with sending the data to the server, which will send back the response (login successful or login failed).  Then you'd only inform the Activity if there was a successful login.  Then your interface would change from a function named onLoginPressed to something like onLoginSuccessful, which will either take no parameters or take any authentication info from the server, depending on how your app works.